# Separating integration tests in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, gradle, integration-testing

I am writing tests for SpringBoot application.
I would like to separate integration tests from unit tests. 
Now my project structure looks something like this:

```
├── Demo
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
|   |   |   └──java
│   │   ├── test
|   |   |   └──java
```

Is there a way to add a module like this:

```
├── Demo
│   ├── src
│   │   ├── main
|   |   |   └──java
│   │   ├── integrationTest
|   |   |   └──java
│   │   ├── test
|   |   |   └──java
```

I would like that new integrationTest module to act the same as test module, but I don't know how to configure it. I managed to add it as module, mark integrationTest/java dir as Test Sources Root and run test in it but @SpringBootTest cannot resolve ApplicationContext, and all of my beans are always null.

When I write the same test in test module, it works fine.

Is there a way to do this?
Is this the right way to separate integration tests?
If not, what is the best practice?

I am working in intelliJ and I am using gradle as package manager.

Comment: The Gradle user manual has a section that describes how to do exactly this <https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests>. You can set the active profile in the integrationTest task definition using something like `systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "integration")`, although I guess you don't really need to if the integration and unit tests sources are separated. Credit to <https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles> for mentioning the system property to set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have them with the rest of the tests; apply a *convention* and tag-match that to filter them out, something like appending `IntegrationTest` to the class name(s) and using the same value for the JUnit `@Tag`... then just define/declare some Gradle tasks to execute them:

```
test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

task integrationTests(type: Test) {
  filter { includes = ["IntegrationTest"] }
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

task unitTests(type: Test) {
  filter { includes = ["UnitTest"] }
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

Full example:

```java
package tld.domain.support;

public final class Category {
  public static final INTEGRATION_TEST = "IntegrationTest";

  public static final UNIT_TEST = "UnitTest";
}
```

```java
import tld.domain.support.Category;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Tag(Category.INTEGRATION_TEST)
final class MyIntegrationTest {
  @Test
  void testFoo() {
    // ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @iboisver's comment, you can separate them and are encouraged to do so in the [gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests). You basically have to:

1. Create a new directory under `src` (i.e. `src/integrationTest`)
2. Add the source set in the `build.gradle` file along with it's configurations:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
        runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + sourceSets.test.output
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntime
}
```

3. Create an `integrationTests` task to run your integration tests, and attach it to the `check` task (also in `build.gradle`):

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description = 'Runs integration tests.'
    group = 'verification'

    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    shouldRunAfter test
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

I found a couple of very helpful articles ([1](https://tomgregory.com/gradle-integration-tests/), [2](https://inspeerity.com/blog/separate-gradle-tasks-for-unit-and-integration-tests/)) that guided me on my own integration test setup.

NOTE: seems like the whole process is much simpler if you use the [JVM Test Suite  Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html#jvm_test_suite_plugin) (requires Gradle 7.3+), but since it's in incubating state I didn't go with it.